# how to group by on one2many fields - Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo

I Have Something like this:

```
 <tree>

     <field name="field1"/>

     <field name="field2"/>

</tree>
```

I want to use group by in tree view but I don't know how

Answer (score -1):

You cannot group by using One2many fields. Because it is against the very principle of One2many. If one record is related to many models using one to many models, that means that these records are all related to that one record, and only to him.

That does mean that there are no other record like him that has the same One2many field. So all those records have nothing in common, and therefore cannot be grouped at all using this field.